# How to have a unique id between Stripe events

Tags: spring-boot, stripe-payments

I use Stripe checkout for my subscription in my spring application.

```
public StripeCashoutResponse createSession(Transaction transaction){

    Stripe.apiKey = secretKey;
    logger.info("init stripe subscription payment");
    // The price ID passed from the client
    String priceId = passPriceId;

    StripeCashoutResponse cashoutResponse = null;
    SessionCreateParams params = new SessionCreateParams.Builder()
            .setSuccessUrl("https://example.com/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}")
            .setCancelUrl("https://example.com/canceled.html")
            .setMode(SessionCreateParams.Mode.SUBSCRIPTION)
            .setClientReferenceId(transaction.getTransactionId())
            .addLineItem(new SessionCreateParams.LineItem.Builder()
                    // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
                    .setQuantity(1L)
                    .setPrice(priceId)
                    .build()
                    )
            .build();
    
    
    try {
        Session session = Session.create(params);
        StripeResponse response = session.getLastResponse();
        //convert to object to get the url
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        cashoutResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body(), StripeCashoutResponse.class);
        cashoutResponse.setPaymentStatus(session.getPaymentStatus());
        cashoutResponse.setCode(response.code());
        logger.info(cashoutResponse.getUrl());

    } catch (StripeException e) {
        transaction.setStatus(TransactionStatus.PAYMENT_FAILED);
        logger.error("Payment Failed: Unable to process the payment due to an error during the calling of stripe", e);
    }

    return cashoutResponse;
}
```

The response of this call gives me an id like `cs_test_a1GoqW9TGTJgZnGuplZJ49Y2oxD70jtLKXBrVlQA23C7skzUJd8GlUJZSY` and I save this id in my database.

Once the subscription is validated, i receive multiple events in my webhooks :

```
charge.succeeded
payment_method.attached
customer.created
customer.updated
customer.subscription.created
customer.subscription.updated
payment_intent.succeeded
payment_intent.created
invoice.created
invoice.finalized
invoice.updated
invoice.paid
invoice.payment_succeeded
checkout.session.completed
```

We want to handle the event `invoice.payment_succeeded` but this event doesn't have the id we saved in the first step of the checkout.

The id we save in the first step is present only in the last step `checkout.session.completed`.

During the first checkout session, we don't have the subscription id.

Now I don't know how to do to have an id I can save in the first step (checkout) and I can find it in my event `invoice.payment_succeeded`, so when this event is sent by Stripe, i can handle it correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using Checkout, Stripe recommends relying on the `checkout.session.completed` Event for fulfillment. They document this in details in their documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders).

The problem is that you get a lot of other Event types during the completion of the payment on Checkout and you don't have an easy way to know whether to ignore those. What I would recommend is adding custom metadata to the underlying Subscription that will be created by Checkout. This is done by passing the `subscription_data[metadata]` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-metadata). Doing this will ensure that the resulting Subscription will have the metadata set on it. The resulting Invoice(s) will also have a copy of that metadata under the `subscription_details[metadata]` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-subscription_details-metadata).

Now with that approach, when you get the `customer.subscription.*` or `invoice.paid` Events you can look up the relevant metadata to match it to your internal database record for this order/payment.

Finally, Stripe recommends ignoring `invoice.payment_succeeded` and instead relying on `invoice.paid`. That Event type is newer and fixed some long standing issues such as firing for Invoices where the amount is below the minimum amount as Stripe consider those paid.

Comment: but when we have a renew of a subscription, stripe doesn't sent `checkout.session.completed`. We have all of them except the last one. This is why I try to use  `invoice.payment_succeeded`

Comment: Do not use `invoice.payment_succeeded`, ignore it completely, use `invoice.paid` instead. I also explained how to set metadata so that you can connect the Event to the right Checkout Session if you prefer only using that Event and not the Checkout one for the first Event.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after days of discussion with the Stripe team, it is not possible to have a unique id during the checkout. Even if you add a metadata, these metadata won't be available in all events.